# Osgi a container or framework

Tags: frameworks, osgi, containers

Hi I am a newbee to osgi . Could anyone please help me understand that whether osgi is a container or framework? Can anybody please explain the difference between the two as well. Thanks it will be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what **you** mean by those terms, there's no universally-accepted definition of either.

From my perspective, OSGi is not really a container since it does not wrap around your code or change the execution model. So I prefer the term framework, and indeed most of the documentation refers to it as "the OSGi Framework" or sometimes "the OSGi Service Platform".

For example: you can create a running and useful OSGi Framework in just 5-10 lines of Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a framework as a library that you code against and that has control over the execution. So e.g. spring is a framework and OSGi in the same way.

A container is a generic application you can start up and where you can deploy executeable artifacts. OSGi by default does not allow you to deploy artifacts. It mainly provides and API that allows you to load and start bundles. In practice though pretty much all OSGi implementations allow deployments like from a certain directory. So at least the implementations are also containers.

Like Neil wrote my definition is not the only one so the above may not be universally true.

Comment: what i have understood from tutorials as.. osgi is a specification that defines how modules can be managed as bundles and how they can interact and the containers are the implementation of those osgi specifications. Now does osgi also provide some libraries that we can use so that we can create bundles (this way it acts as framework as well)?

Comment: You have understood this right. OSGi is mainly a spec that only lives in its implementations. So you have to choose one of the implementations. The most popular are Apache Felix and Eclipse Equinox. If you plan to use OSGi on the server side I recommend Apache Karaf which uses Felix or Equinox and adds a lot of management features.